# TangoSupport_detectCorners parameter "point_of_interest"

Tags: android, c++, google-project-tango

I'm wondering what exactly need to be passed as point_of_interest into TangoSupport_detectCorners function? The doc only says "the user-specified location" which is very ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Corners are sorted based on distances to the input POI. Usually you can pass in a 3D point where user is interested in(i.e., by pressing on screen).